# Excel Show money in bank today

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with a few columns: `date`, `incoming and outgoing money` , `type` and `cumulative`, and `money remaining`.

I want to have at the top of my sheet in the locked panes a cell to display the cumulative money remaining on today's date.

So I want it to look through Column A and find today's date or the closest date to today then get the value out of that row in column E. How the hell do I do this, I have tried a few different ways and nothing has worked.

I currently have conditional formatting on the rows that will highlight the sort of most current. I was only able to do that with `=AND($A2<=TODAY(),$A2>=TODAY()-3)`, but the problem with this is that anything 3 days before today is highlighted so it doesn't work very well. I really want only one row highlighted that is today's date or the closest below today.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP in conjunction with TODAY() will be your friend

> > =VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A4:E17,5)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like usual when I give up I find the answer figure out how to do it so here is how I did it.

=VLOOKUP(INDEX($A$2:$A$200, MATCH(TODAY(), $A$2:$A$200, 1)),$A$2:$E$250,5,FALSE)

First looked for the closest date then looked up the value in the 5th field and it worked.